# Unity instantiate object at a certain direction based of a spatial anchor

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors, prefab

Having a spatial anchor as a reference point, I wanted to create an object that does not change its location that reference to the spatial anchor.

When creating and saving the initial location of the object that will be spawned later using prefab. I make use of the difference of the x,y,z coordinate between the spatial anchor and the object and saved it in the cloud. After that, making use of the difference of the x,y,z to load the prefab back to it original position.

when creating the object based off the spatial anchor

[image]

However, upon restarting the application at a different point, the prefab will be shifted based on the start up position of the hololens. Based on what I know, the initial position of the hololens when it starts up in (0,0,0). Hence, the spatial anchor coordinate will be different and causing the prefab to be loaded at a different direction.

upon starting up the app at different location

[image]

Is there any way or solution that I can implement to make the prefab load at the same place as where it is created without it being affected by the hololens location?

Comment: `However, upon restarting the application at a different point, the prefab will be shifted based on the start up position of the hololens` sounds like the spacial anchor isn't working/used then .. HoloLens maps your surroundings and tries to keep spacial anchors in the same real world position as long as it recognizes the environment as the same "room" => walk around a bit more to make sure it recognizes your surroundings as one coherent room

Comment: the spatial anchor remains at its original position. is just that upon starting up the application at a different position, the coordinate will change accordingly based on the users location. 

For example, when i create the spatial anchor the coordinate is (1,1,1) but when i move 1m away and restart the application. I spawn the spatial anchor the position still remain the same but just that the coordinate change to probably (2,2,2). hence affecting the spawning of the prefab.

Comment: Yeah but isn't this exactly what you would expect.. the reason why you use a spacial anchor is because you want to anchor your spawned object to a real world position -> of course it will be somewhere else in your virtual Unity coordinates if you moved as the target is not keeping it in the same Unity coordinates but keeping it at the same real world position

Comment: understood. just curious if there is any workaround to spawn the prefab back to its original position without the usage of spatial anchor. I tried to save the angle between the spatial anchor and prefab. After that, instantiate the prefab with its x,y,z, and then rotate back accordingly by the angle. However, didn't manage to do it out, not sure did I coded it out incorrectly or if my logic/concept is wrong.

Comment: I think this is still a logic issue tbh ... ou either want to keep the object at the same real world position anchored in your room -> you use the spacial anchor .. and that's it. Or you want the object at the same Unity coordinates -> you don't use spacial anchor at all ...

Answer (score 0):

If your prefab is a child of the anchor you could do something like this to save the position relative to the anchor:

```
var localPos = spawned.transform.localPosition;
var localRot = spawned.transform.localEulerAngles;
var localSca = spawned.transform.localScale;
        
var prefab = new Prefab
{
   AnchorId = anchorId,
   PosX = localPos.x,
   PosY = localPos.y,
   PosZ = localPos.z,
   RotX = localRot.x,
   RotY = localRot.y,
   RotZ = localRot.z,
   ScaX = localSca.x,
   ScaY = localSca.y,
   ScaZ = localSca.z
};
```

Save prefab to the cloud.

And then when you are starting a new session and you locate the anchor, you'd spawn the prefab as a child of the anchor and set the transform from the data you stored previously:

```
spawned.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(prefab.PosX, prefab.PosY, prefab.PosZ);
spawned.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(prefab.RotX, prefab.RotY, prefab.RotZ);
spawned.transform.localScale = new Vector3(prefab.ScaX, prefab.ScaY, prefab.ScaZ);
```